# Documents list not exsists when activating feature

Tags: 2013, feature-receiver, web-template

I have created a custom web template based on Team Site and added a `SPWeb` scoped feature to add a List View WebPart to it. It throws an exception when it comes to `web.Lists["Documents"]` and says **documents not exists**. But when the web is created it has a documents list. I tried to add a call back as follows to be sure that the web is provisioned. The site is created however it still does not contains a `listviewWebpart`.

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
 {
     var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AddWebParts), web.Site.ID);
 }

  private void AddWebParts(object state)
    {
        Guid siteId = (Guid)state;
        SPWeb web = null;

        while (true)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
            {
                using (web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    if (true == web.Provisioned)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
   ....
  and so on to add listview webpart
 }
```

Comment: in your site, goto siteactions and check to see the full lists of document librarys and list! check to make sure Documents exists and that its called Documents ;) also make sure that the feature that your activating is the same spweb that contains the list/document library

Comment: thanks ali but it is not the case, I solved it by using a Web event receiver so that it adds the listview webpart when the web provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the features creating the Document Library and the page are prior to your feature in the Onet.xml. See [Site Definitions vs. Web Templates](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx) for the order things are provisioned in.

Comment: Thanks, as I wrote in my question, I have copied directly the onet.xml so it should have same features that oob site definiton has. Do I need to add some oob features? which one?